# Use of instagram public media data

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm a mobile developer, and I'm working on an app that's loading images from some instagram-users. The app doesn't post anything to instagram and I don't want to bother my app-users with a login screen to instagram. So I want the app-user to be able to view instagram photos from other instagram-users.

If **I use the "http://instagram.com/USERNAME/media/"-method**, am I still required to comply with the API rate limits? **What license does this use fall under?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about using an API, but rather a legal question about the license of the data and inherently not a programming question. This will differ depending on jurisdiction.

Comment: You want to load in the public data form instagram. Notice that some IG users have set their profile to private, in that case you are unable to load in any data from that specific user.